# Clang static analyzer - parameter with unspecified nullability made "more" unspecified by conditional?

Tags: c++, nullable, clang-static-analyzer

The following:

```
int dummyStrlen (const char* /*str*/ __attribute__((nonnull))) {
    return 42;
}

void f (const char* s) {
    if (s != nullptr) printf ("notnull"); // Commenting-out this line removes the warning
    if (dummyStrlen (s) > 0) printf ("length OK");
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/WfIQ19lZ22Mc1bk9

triggers a warning by Clang's static analyzer:

> Null pointer passed as an argument to a 'nonnull' parameter

Commenting out the conditional test for `s` being not `nullptr` removes the warning. Is this the intended behavior or is this an issue with the analyzer?

In more detail:

First, is it the intended behavior for such a conditional to change the analyzer's assumptions about the parameter's nullability? I can believe it, it makes sense. I was just surprised by it and I don't know if that is indeed the case.

Second, it looks like the conditional changes the parameter's nullability attribute (at least as far as the analyzer is concerned) to unspecified, causing the warning. But I assume the default for parameters without a nullability attribute specified is *already* unspecified. Is this a wrong assumption? Or perhaps the conditional makes `s` *more* unspecified (i.e. suspicious) as far as the analyzer is concerned?

Note the above is also affected by the witnessed usage of `f`, if such usage exists:

```
int main() {
    // f(nullptr);                   // Uncommenting this call reintroduces the warning even if the check for nullptr in f is commented-out
    // f("Thanks for all the fish"); // Uncommenting this call suppresses the warning if the above call with nullptr is not also uncommented
}
```

Comment: aside - is there a way to run the Clang static analyzer on Wandbox in a way which doesn't trigger a Permission Error?

Comment: You have a check for `s != nullptr` in your function, but if `s == nullptr` you still unconditionally call `dummyStrlen`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude right. But I also call it unconditionally if I comment-out that check, yet the warning doesn't appear in that case.

Comment: AFAICT, the conditional marks `s` as `nullable`. By default `s` is unspecified. But if you check it against `nullptr` the analyser correctly assumes that the value is nullable as it would be a redundant check otherwise. Now that it is considered nullable, the warning should not be surprising.

Comment: @idmean That makes sense. Indeed, I wasn't clear on the difference between unspecified and explicitly (or, in this case, implicitly) nullable.